# How do I parse Haskell source into an AST in Haskell?

Tags: parsing, haskell, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to parse a Haskell source file into an AST.  I'm new to parsers so I'm not sure how to make my own.  I was just wondering if there is a function that takes a file and returns an AST.  I also thought it might work to turn a file into a string using `readFile` and then parsing the string, but I still don't know where to go from there.  Is there some well-known way to do this?  If not, how can I do it myself?

Comment: What syntax are you supposed to be parsing?  Haskell?  Something else?

Comment: Haskell.  Sorry I forgot to be specific.

Comment: Have you looked at the `haskell-src-exts` package. In particular, the [`Language.Haskell.Exts.Parser`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/haskell-src-exts/1.13.5/doc/html/Language-Haskell-Exts-Parser.html) module contains parsers for many kinds of Haskell AST fragments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Language.Haskell.Meta.Parse](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/haskell-src-meta/0.0.6/doc/html/Language-Haskell-Meta-Parse.html). In particular, `parseHsModule` will parse an entire module for you. There are also functions for parsing smaller chunks, such as `parseExp` which parses an expression.